# Rugged Effect on Trash and Workspace viewer

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel

There are 2 elements (maybe more) than when I right click on them they give a "rugged" effect to the menu. So far the only 2 I have found are Trash and Workspace Viewer. The image shows how I see the trash when I right click on it:

[image]

How can I fix this. Am using an Nvidia card. It looks like this on Gnome Classic (Both version with and without effects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/711746).

A workaround is to alter the theme file for the panel:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/gnome-panel.rc`
2. At the top part of the file, add this new style:

   ```
   style "panel-applet-context-menu" = "dark"
   {
       xthickness = 0
       ythickness = 0

       bg[NORMAL] = "#4b4a46"

       engine "murrine" {
           textstyle = 2
           text_shade = 0.35
       }
   }
   ```
3. Change

   ```
   widget "*PanelApplet*"            style "panel"
   ```

   to

   ```
   widget "*PanelApplet*"            style "panel-applet-context-menu"
   ```
4. Save and run 
   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `killall gnome-panel`